# how do check jquery ajax post sucess or not success?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following jQuery code, but it's not running the alert.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

```
jQuery('.list_action .edit').click(function(){      
    var answerId = jQuery(this).parent().next('#answer_id').val();
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url : 'form.php',
        data: {'answer_id':answerId},
        dataType : 'json',
    }).done(function(result){
        if(result == true){
            alert('success');
        }else{
            alert('faild');
        }                       
    }); 
 });
```

in file php i have code

```
echo $response = json_encode($answersAjax->getData());
```

Many thank!

Comment: There's nothing essentially wrong with the javascript as provided.  Assuming you have a matching html element and the `click` event if firing then it's most likely your url is not being hit or not returning correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Try to see if an error was returned from the server by including "error: function" in the call:

```
var data = "answer_id="+answer_id;
req = $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    encoding:"UTF-8",
    url: 'index.php',
    cache: false,
    data: data,
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        //alert(xhr.responseText);
        alert("Error: "+thrownError);
    },
    xhr: function () {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
        return xhr;
    },
    beforeSend: function () {
        //do sth

    },
    complete: function () {
        //do sth
    },
    success: function (response) {

         alert("success");

    }
});
```

If you have more than one variable, then use

```
var data = "var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2+"&var3="+var3
```

If you still don't get anything back, then your url is not correct. Did you try to output some text in your server code, to see if you received the request at all? E.g.:

```
echo "answer id=".$_POST['answer_id'];
```

If you don't see at least "answer id=" then you know that the URL is certainly not correct!

Comment: when i ruu code get error `yntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 804 of the JSON data`

Comment: See my edit. Try "var data = "answer_id="+answer_id" instead of json

Comment: I changed the code above. You can combine them using the "&" character. For example var data = "var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2+"&var3="+var3  where var1, var2 and var3 are your variables

Comment: Ok great! It would be nice, if you could accept the answer then (check button on the left of the answer). Thank!